# A map between Model and table

Tags: magento, orm, magento-1.7

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2, and I wonder if there is a map/list that reference between Model and actually table in db. For example,

```
Mage::getModel('review/review')
```

get back the instance that represent table `review_detail`. Is there a map/list that aggregate these information for quick reference?

Comment: you need to display query for that collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no relationship between Models and tables, instead a resource class is used which helps in making the relationship with the table.

For e.g. 
In `Mage_Review_Model_Review`

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('review/review');
}
```

Defines the resource it has to connect to, i.e. `Mage_Review_Model_Resource_Review`

Inside the resource class `Mage_Review_Model_Resource_Review`

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('review/review', 'review_id'); //defines the XML node in config it has to look for table name, and the primary field
    $this->_reviewTable         = $this->getTable('review/review');
    $this->_reviewDetailTable   = $this->getTable('review/review_detail');
    $this->_reviewStatusTable   = $this->getTable('review/review_status');
    $this->_reviewEntityTable   = $this->getTable('review/review_entity');
    $this->_reviewStoreTable    = $this->getTable('review/review_store');
    $this->_aggregateTable      = $this->getTable('review/review_aggregate');
}
```

Inside `config.xml` within the module's `etc` folder, it looks for following path for table name **`config\global\models\review_resource\entities\review`**